# Make button click work for once

Tags: vb.net, button, checkbox, textbox, click

How can I tell the code to not to write the word to textbox for every click on the button?

When both checkboxes are clicked both, text must be written in adding order but when I click the button again text shouldn't be doubled or multiplied.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            TextBox1.Text += ("hello ")
        End If
        If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
            TextBox1.Text += ("please help")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Boolean variable for each if statement, i.e. each check box. Set them to false initially and change your code to look something like this

```
If CheckBox1.Checked = True And CheckBox1Bool = False Then
    TextBox1.Text += ("hello ")
    CheckBox1Bool = True
End If
If CheckBox2.Checked = True And CheckBox2Bool = False Then
    TextBox1.Text += ("please help")
    CheckBox2Bool = True
End If
```

**EDIT:**

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Bool1 As Boolean
    Dim Bool2 As Boolean

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True And Not Bool1 Then
            TextBox1.Text += ("hello ")
            Bool1 = True
        End If
        If CheckBox2.Checked = True And Not Bool2 Then
            TextBox1.Text += ("please help")
            Bool2 = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

This works and as you can see I haven't changed the code only added in what I suggested to you.

Comment: `Dim CheckBox1Bool As Boolean` The default value of a Boolean in VB is false so you don't even need to set the value at first

Comment: Yes, and declare it as from member, not as local variable.

Comment: I prefer to write `If CheckBox1.Checked And Not CheckBox1Bool Then`.

Comment: thank you for your concern but this is not i am asking for. in this way if i click the button again the text which coded to checkboxes goes on to be written on to textbox again and again. if i click the button three times words are being written for three times.. i want to make it for only once even after i click the button for ten or twenty times...

Comment: then the scope of the boolean variables is not correct. The scope has to be greater than what you have it as

Comment: the code now is this; and is not working in that purpose
'Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim CheckBox1Bool As Boolean

        If CheckBox1.Checked And Not CheckBox1Bool Then

            TextBox1.Text += ("hello ")

            CheckBox1Bool = True
        End If
        Dim CheckBox2Bool As Boolean
        If CheckBox2.Checked And Not CheckBox2Bool Then
            TextBox1.Text += ("please help")
            CheckBox2Bool = True
        End If
    End Sub'

Comment: There you go, hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Just reset your Checkbox.Checked event in your Button Click event. That way it will not send the text again till you reselect it.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        CheckBox1.Checked = False
        TextBox1.Text += ("hello ")
    End If
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        CheckBox2.Checked = False
        TextBox1.Text += ("please help")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your concern about my problem. after i checked your solutions i went to bed. i released stg just i was going to sleep and opened pc again and solved my silly problem with this thing.. this works perfect for me :)

```
    Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Textbox1.Text= ("")
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        TextBox1.Text += ("hello ")
    End If
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        TextBox1.Text += ("please help")
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class